# JSON as source dataset in Data Factory Azure

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

There were no answers in documentations, msdn blogs, nowhere.

I need to use data from JSON as a source dataset in Data Factory.
I take this JSON from web but I can't use WebLinkedService because it is not html page (examined).

What kind of LinkedService and input Dataset should I use?
Maybe there is some possibility in Azure to put automatically JSON into storage blob?

Comment: guess u have the answer there. u can store the json in blob storage and take it from there.

Comment: it would be easy in the case of single operation. But I want to load a few JSONs (with the same keys but different values) per day. So then the JSONs should be automatically stored in blob, not manually.

Comment: depends on how/ where you are getting the json from. you can always automate it to upload to blob. if the scale is higher then you can look at documentdb which is a json database.

Comment: Where is the json data coming from? If you are getting the json data from a web service then your best bet would probably be to use a custom .net activity. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/